# WPF ListView - Group data but also displaying "ungrouped" data

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

I'm trying to display a list of Item's in a ListView, but also group them by Category if they have one, otherwise display them in the root.

[image: Items]

Here's what i'm trying to achieve.

[image: ListView Example]

CollectionViewSource doesn't seem to support this behavior, as adding a PropertyGroupDescription will simple display data with a group (and ignore the rest).

Answer (score 0):

The "ungrouped" data is still a group - so to achieve that behaviour I would create a ContainerStyleSelector on your groupstyle to display the last items in a stackpanel instead of an expander.